# I am getting (eval):1: invalid Unicode codepoint error while trying to scrape instagram

Tags: ruby, eval, nokogiri

I am trying to scrape data from instagram. Here is my code

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'json'
require "unicode/emoji"

def get_html
    url = 'https://www.instagram.com/muriithi_kabogo/'
    html = open(url)

end

def pass_data
    html = get_html
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
end

def get_data
    profiles = []
    body  = pass_data.at('body')
    script = body.at('script').text
    myText = script
    json_object_data = eval(myText)

end


get_data()
```

When I try to change the text into json format, I get an error:

```
(eval):1: invalid Unicode codepoint (SyntaxError)
usinessmen #beautiful #smile\ud83d\ude0a #teambringit #shebr
```

How do I move past this error?

Comment: Re-encode the string or use proper encoding. That is some type of emoticon or something.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 I have re- endoced myText using scrip.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8) but still I get the same error. Yes,they are emoticons. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: `force_encoding` doesn't encode the string, it just forces the string to be interpreted as whatever encoding you set, useful if you have a code that Ruby may assume as ASCII or something, but is actually UTF-8, you can tell to it treat it as UTF-8. `encode` will actually convert the bytes.String encoding in Ruby can be bothersome compared to other languages...

Comment: Got the answer I needed from. Thanks for your assistance. Check the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON, like JavaScript, uses UCS2 encoding, which Ruby chokes on.

Do not use `evil`. For one thing, Ruby will detect `\ud83d\ude0a` as invalid codepoints, as it should; for another, it is a security hole; and lastly, it slows down your code.

Use `JSON.parse`, which is safer, faster, and knows how to deal with UCS2:

```
require 'json'
json_str = '"usinessmen #beautiful #smile\ud83d\ude0a #teambringit #shebr"'
JSON.parse(json_str)
# => "usinessmen #beautiful #smile #teambringit #shebr"
```